# Variable row length Solver optimization

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, solver

lets say i have four columns (U, W,X,Y) . the relationship at the end should be W(i)=X(i) , Y(i) = 0 because Y= X-Y and U(i) is variable. You change the values in column "U" and bring W=X and all values must be positive W,X,Y,U. This is my code and it is not working.

lRo = Sheets("Rohr-Bogen").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

```
SolverReset
solverprecision = 0.0001
SolverOk SetCell:="$Y$12:$Y$" & lRo, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$U12$:$U$" & lRo
SolverAdd cellRef:="$W$12:$W$" & lRo, relation:=2, formulaText:="$X$12:$X$" & lRo
SolverAdd cellRef:="$X$12:$X$" & lRo, relation:=3, formulaText:=0
SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

    If Range("W10").Value > 0.0001 Then
    Call solve
    End If
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: At a glance... is there a reason your using VBA versus in sheet Goal Seek?

Comment: There is no special reason , i used to use solver more often. If goal seek performs better then i have no problem to use goal seek.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SolverAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838657(v=office.15).aspx) function instead. The form of this function is

```
SolverAdd(CellRef, Relation, FormulaText)
```

where

- `CellRef` is the range of the formula cells (in your case the Y cells).
- `Relation` can be a number that corresponds to  `<=`, `>=`, `=`, `integer`, `binary`, `alldifferent`.
- `FormulaText` a Range that has the desired (target) values of `CellRef`.

Based on your code, here is a demonstration. It is untested, as it is not clear which cells on your spreadsheet are formulas and which are values, but it should get you started:

```
'First I define an enumeration to make clear what 1, 2, 3 etc mean:
'For details check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838657(v=office.15).aspx
Enum tRelationship
  Const tRelationship_leq = 1  ' Stands for <=
  Const tRelationship_eq = 2   ' Stands for =
  Const tRelationship_geq = 3  ' ...
  Const tRelationship_int = 4
  Const tRelationship_bin = 5
  Const tRelationship_alldiff = 6
End Enum

 Sub solve()

lRo = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    SolverReset
    ' Change K7 with the range that solves all variables
    SolverOk SetCell:="$W$10", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$K$7" 'solves first W10 = 0
    SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

    ' Here I assume that last row is row 16. You can change that dynamically as you do
    ' in your code. No loop is necessary. I assume that Y12 = X12 - W12, Y13 = ..., etc.
    SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("Y12:Y16"), relation:=tRelationship_eq, formulaText:=0
    SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub
```

The fact that you are solving one model only, that sets `W10` to zero, provides a guarantee that if there exists a feasible solution (with `X = W`), it will be found.

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

A quick summary of how the solver works:

- Changes a range of given cells (called *Decision Variable cells* -
  specified in `SolverOK-->ByChange`) so that
- a given cell (**only one cell**, called *Target Cell* or *Objective
  Function cell* - specified in `SolverOK-->SetCell`), whose value depends on the Decision Variable cells,
  is minimized, or maximized, or reaches a given value (`SolverOK-->MaxMinVal` and `ValueOf` if `MaxMinVal=3`) **and**
- A range of other cells, **that depend on the Decision Variable cells**, satisfies certain constraints (the `SolverAdd` part as described above).

In the updated version of the code that you posted:

- `SolverOK-->SetCell` is given a range of cells, which will fail (see [here the documentation for SetCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839427%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).
- The `SolverAdd` parts are overcomplicated (and incorrect). **Assuming the the `X(i)` and `Y(i)` have formulas that refer to the `U` cells**, then if `Y(i) = X(i) - W(i)` we only need this line:

`SolverAdd cellRef:="$Y$12:$Y$" & lRo, relation:=2, formulaText:=0`

Setting the `Y` cells to zero makes sure that `X(i)=W(i)` because `Y(i) = X(i) - W(i)`.

- The last part of your code is somewhat confusing. You check the value of `W10`, but `W10` is nowhere in the model. Is `W10` linked to the `U(i)` cells? If you want your `W10` equal to zero, you can put it in the objective function, and use `MaxMinVal := 3` and `ValueOf := 0`, again, assuming that it is linked to the `U` cells.

In summary, the solver changes only the Decision variable cells (`U(i)`). The cell that we require to be minimized/maximized/equal to value, and also the cells that should be `>=`, `<=`, or `=` to a numeric value should all be linked to the `U(i)` cells.

I hope this makes it clearer?

Comment: Sorry, It did not work. How do you change column "T" & i ? in order to bring x=w , i need to change column  "T" & i.

Comment: You can specify all the changing cells at the argument `ByChange` of `SolverOK`.

Comment: In order to bring in `X=W` it is standard practice to introduce `X-Y` in another cell and set that other cell equal to zero via `SolverAdd`. If any of the entries in X and Y are linked to T then T needs to be in the decision variables (as above comment).

Comment: usually it is not possible to get exactly "0" , i say 0.000001. is it ok?.

Comment: Yes, solver would do that in any case because it works with floating point arithmetic. You can also indicate `value of min`, if the expression is going to be positive anyway, in which case it will go as close to zero as possible. But "value of zero" should return something like 10e-6 in any case.

Comment: Also, Note that the VBA solver commands are in direct correspondence with the solver interface. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945693/excel-solver-with-non-adjacent-cell-constraint/24949080#24949080) is an example of how the solver interface works.

Comment: ok i tried ..it does not work ....this is my code but it does not seems to be workingSolverReset
    solverprecision = 0.0001
    SolverOk SetCell:="$Y$12:$Y$" & lRo, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$U12$:$U$" & lRo
    SolverAdd cellRef:="$W$12:$W$" & lRo, relation:=2, formulaText:="$X$12:$X$" & lRo
    SolverAdd cellRef:="$X$12:$X$" & lRo, relation:=3, formulaText:=0
    SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    
        If Range("W10").Value > 0.0001 Then
        Call solve
        End If

Comment: Could you update the question with the code from your comment? Then it will be easier to read and more visible to the community. If you think it is appropriate, post a link to a spreadsheet that contains a minimal example of the problem (as it stands no one can reproduce the problem). This normally speeds ups resolving drastically. I Will reply asap to the above, but also consider this suggestion (then I can almost guarantee a solution :)).

Comment: Just updated my question. it seems we can set only one target cell per solver. is it right?

Comment: @Shan, I have updated the answer, making clearer how the solver works and what you might need in this case.